# MS Access Create Date Range based on Start Date and End Date

Tags: ms-access

I have a macro which records employee absences using a dynamic calendar I created in a userform. When the employees choose their absence type, they can either enter a start date and end date (for absences longer than 1 day) or they can click on the calendar's cells to choose specific dates. This information is then sent to an Access database where the information is stored and used for generating reports.

My problem is that people find it easier to click on days which follow to apply their absences rather than manually typing in the start and end dates. I now see that the design could have been improved...

The effect this has on the database is there are many "redundant" records in the database. For those who are visual, here is an example what the database is now like and what it could be like:

Current way (bad way):

```
EmployeeName   AbsenceType   StartDate    EndDate
============   ===========   ==========   ==========
Employee1      Vacation      2018-09-24   2018-09-24
Employee1      Vacation      2018-09-25   2018-09-25
Employee1      Vacation      2018-09-26   2018-09-26
Employee1      Vacation      2018-09-27   2018-09-27
Employee1      Vacation      2018-09-28   2018-09-28
```

Hopeful way (better way):

```
EmployeeName   AbsenceType   StartDate    EndDate
============   ===========   ==========   ==========
Employee1      Vacation      2018-09-24   2018-09-28
```

Can anyone suggest how to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could remove the "dynamic control", and force the user to enter a start date and end date via 2 date text fields. Access supports a date picker for text fields tied to a date-type field, so users could still use a calendar.

Comment: Thanks @Zack, I understand and have already corrected the situation for absences going forth from today, however my question was to see if there was something to be done with the entries already in the database.

Comment: Just to make sure: The data resides in an Access table, right? It's not linked to something like SQL Server, is it? If the data is in Access, you might have to resort to looping over the data in VBA to make your updates.

Comment: I believe you can do this using a data macro too. I'm trying to write something up. Data macros can recursively call themselves, which makes it interesting

Comment: That's correct @Zack the data is in Access, not in an SQL database. I assumed I would have to loop through the records, but wanted to make sure a query wouldn't be a possibility.

Comment: See what @ErikvonAsmuth comes up with: I'm not as familar with data macros, and he has the skillz anyways. :)

Comment: Perhaps go with Gustav's solution, recursive data macros for this problem are proving difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *Cartesian* query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Tens]+[Ones] AS Factor, 
    10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) AS Tens, 
    Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Ones
FROM 
    MSysObjects AS Uno, 
    MSysObjects AS Deca;
```

Save it as *qdyFactor* and create another query to generate the dates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    PersonID, 
    DateAdd("d",[Factor],[Start Date]) AS [First Date],
    [End Date]
FROM 
    tblTable,
    qdyFactor
WHERE 
    qdyFactor.Factor Between 0 And DateDiff("d",[Start Date],[End Date]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Gustav for taking the time to answer my question. I understand what the first query does (although I had no idea this could be done with Access!), but even after reading about Cartesian queries yesterday and today, I'm still a little foggy as to how they work and I don't understand what the query is returning. I assumed this would return less lines than my original tables, but it has generated quite a few more. Do you have any suggestions of where I could find more information about Cartesian queries?

Comment: It is simply multiplying. The idea is to input your start and end date, then produce a record for each day - to free the user from this task.

Comment: maybe I'm not understanding what comes next. I don't want all the dates to appear, I want to have all consecutive dates appear in one row instead of many.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You could create a loop the looked for missing dates, then started over if one was found, but when should it stop, and what to do with those records between the start and end?